# Progress Bar Challenge

Tags: javascript

I am currently solving the following JS challenge.

> We want to display the progress that a TV show or ad has made.
> We have already prepared a pretty cool progressbar to display the
> progress. But the length of the progressbar and the duration of the
> shows vary. Implement the getProgress(width:int, duration:int,
> current:int) function that returns the position of the progressbar in
> pixel, px.

> As an example, the function call getProgress(500, 90, 16) should
> return 89. Always round to the nearest whole number.

The problem here is, that I don't get the expected result **89** when I do the math. Why they expect **89** is a riddle to me...Below my code.

```
export function getProgress(width, duration, current) {
    const currentMin = duration / 100 * current
    const pixPerMin = width / duration

    const currentPosition = currentMin * pixPerMin
    return Math.ceil(currentPosition)
}
```

With my function I get 80 which should be correct - or at least I think it's correct. I am probably overlooking something or making a obvious mistake but can't see it.

Comment: This is the math you need: `Math.round(width * current / duration)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total duration is 90, and the current position is 16, so the process is around 18% complete:

```js
console.log(16 / 90);
```

For a bar that's 500 pixels wide, 17.7778% of that is 88.88889 pixels:

```js
const ratioDone = 16 / 90; // 0 to 1
console.log(500 * ratioDone);
```

That's where 89 comes from.

So you need:

```js
function getProgress(width, duration, current) {
  const ratioDone = current / duration;
  return Math.round(ratioDone * width);
}
console.log(getProgress(500, 90, 16));
```

Comment: Unfortunately with your code, I receive the follwing error:


Error: Custom message:
  Function called: getProgress(200, 37, 100);

expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: 200
Received: 541


The "current" parameter I think is not a time value. I think it's percentage.

Comment: That's a nonsensical input; the current should not be more than the duration. If that's really a possibility you need to account for, then just make sure not to overflow 100%: `Math.min(current, duration)` instead of `current`, or `const radioDone = Math.min(current / duration, 1)`

Comment: You are right. That's why this challenge was so confusing to me. The author should describe the inputs more clearly and check the test cases. Thank you for your input!